# How to get the largest palindromic product PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, optimization

First than nothing I'm not a native guy so sorry for all those mistakes.

I'm trying to get the largest palindromic product between two integers, for example; 3 and 11, the largest will be 11*11=121.

I tried with this.

```
function Pallendrome($str) : bool {
  return (strval($str) == strrev(strval($str))) ? true : false;
}

function largestPalindromicProduct($lower, $upper) {
$array = array();
  for($it=$upper; $it >= $lower; $it--){
    for($it_=$upper; $it_ >= $lower; $it_--){
      $num = $it*$it_;
      if(Pallendrome($num)) { array_push($array, $num); }
    }  
  }

if(empty($array)) { return NAN; }
else{ ksort($array); return $array[0];}

}
```

But, I'd need to get a way to optimize it 'cause it's taking a long time due to the numbers introduced in, are kind of big.

Do you guys have some idea for it? Thank ya!.

Comment: Hint: What does `==` return normally? There's no need to cast a boolean to a boolean using a ternary.

Comment: Why is 11 and 3 "11 * 11"? How are you determining what is a palindrome?

Comment: So if the numbers given are "14" and "7", the largest product would be "7 * 7" because "1414" isn't a palindrome?

Comment: @Anthony I think the challenge is to find the largest number which is a palindrome and is the product of two numbers in the given range. So, for 7 and 14, the answer would be 11 * 11 = 121.

Comment: @Anthony Nope, pallendrome of two products (min and max), 7*7 will be 49, it does not a pallendrome, but 11*11 = 121 this one is pallendrome.

Comment: I think the idea is that it finds the largest palindrome number between those to numbers, and then get the square of that number. You think it's to find a product of two numbers that are in the given range?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yep! The problem is, those "for"... I'm forced to used ksort 'cause for example:

10 * 10 = 100.
10 * 9 = 90
10 * 8 = 80 but 9 * 9 = 81, and this is bigger than the last one. So, those fors are kind useless, just useful to get all pallendrome, and with Ksort return the first one, it would be the bigger one.

That's the mainly reason because my code isn't optimize it.

Comment: Well at the very least, you don't need to save all the values in an array, you can just store the largest one so far in a variable and then overwrite that variable.

Comment: Huh. Would it be easier to get the lowest possible produce (for 3 and 11, that would be 3 * 11 =  33) and the highest possible product (for 3 and 11, that would be 11 * 11 = 121) and find the first palindrome number (starting at the highest product) when counting by 1? Wouldn't any integer between the range of products (between 33 and 121) be expressed as a product of some numbers falling inside that range?

Comment: Also, how big are we talking about these possible inputs? up to 5 digits? 10?

Comment: There are 1099 palindromic integers that are 5 digits or less. I'm wondering if it would be easier to store those first and then check which one shows up first when cycling through all the potential products.

Comment: @Anthony as far as I know, 12 digits

Comment: Also, if you defer the Pallendrome() check until after you already have verified that the new number is larger than the largest so far, then you can skip almost all of the calls to Pallendrome(), which are fairly expensive. For example: `if ($num > $largest && Pallendrome($num)) { $largest = $num; }` This way, the function call never happens when you already know you can't use the number.

Comment: Also, just inline the code that's in the function, then you're avoiding a function call: `if ($num > $largest && $num == strrev($num)) { $largest = $num; }`

Comment: And you are just wanting to find the largest number, not preserve which two numbers in the given range actually produced that number?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I tried with that, I mean it makes sense and it's better than my code, but I still get execution time out, (I know I could change it, but I need in the time they have given me).

Comment: @Anthony Yep, just the largest number, I don't care how I got it.

Comment: You could also abort as soon as you know you can't possibly get a larger number. If you're on the very first iteration of a subloop and the product isn't larger than your largest, then it can never be (since you're counting down) and you can immediately abort. Something like this: `if ($it_ == $upper && $num <= $largest) { break 2; }`

Comment: @AlexHowansky I'm sorry but I don't find sense to that code, I mean, $it_ wouldn't be $upper anymore after the first iteration.

How could I know when the $it_ * $it gonna return always fewer than $largest? Because, as I said, 9*9 is > than 10*8 and 9*9 is far away of 10*10 in those iterarions. I'm really sorry for my english, I know there's a lot of mistakes...

Comment: For example, if range is 1-10, the for would works like 10*10, 10*9, 10*8, 10*7...... and then 9*10, 9*8, 9*7..... But 10*8 < 9*9.

Comment: If you use 3 and 14, you will count down until you find 11 * 11 = 121. Then you'll keep checking 10*14, 10*13... and 9*14, 9*13... and 8*14, 8*13... and so on, all the way down to 1*14, 1*13... However, note that 8 * 14 = 112. Once you hit that point, there is no possible way to get a number larger than 121 -- so you can skip everything from 8 * 14 down to 1 * 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the folks over at math.stackexchange.com could help you with a better algorithm, but for the purposes of optimizing what you've got thus far, here's a summation of all my comments:

```
function largestPalindromicProduct($lower, $upper)
{
    $largest = 0;
    for ($it = $upper; $it >= $lower; $it--) {
        for ($it_ = $upper; $it_ >= $lower; $it_--) {
            $num = $it * $it_;

            // If we're on the first iteration and we have a product lower than the
            // largest we've found so far, then we know we can never get a larger
            // number (because we're counting down) and we can abort immediately.
            if ($num <= $largest) {
                if ($it_ == $upper) {
                    break 2;
                }
                // Otherwise, we can at least abort the rest of this subloop.
                break;
            }

            // Only check if it's a palindrome once we've passed all the other checks.
            if ($num == strrev($num)) {
                $largest = $num;
            }

        }
    }
    return $largest;
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, Now I got it, thank you for the quick response and effort in it, even with that optimization I still get 'time out', such a pity. This was an exercise from codewars, maybe it's kinda hard than I just thought, so it's okay, I should try something easier... Thank you a lot Alex! :)

Comment: Made another edit to abort subloop remainders, try that? Takes .19 sec on my old laptop for values 12345 and 56789.

Comment: Wait, for some reason it works perfectly now! (They using some tests in order to test if it works, and some of them are random numbers, I guess it's due to this time those numbers weren't as larger as the first time?) 

Anyway, it works, though I have not solved it by myself..  thank you a lot! :) Edit: I just have noticed it works because the second break... Wow...

Comment: I can't edit anymore my last message, so yep, your last edit works perfectly, thank you so much Alex :)